# using std::async appear error: "No viable overloaded '='"

Tags: c++

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>


void f(int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Thread[%d]: %d\n",std::this_thread::get_id(), i);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int thCNT = 5;
    std::future<int> mTH[thCNT];
    
    for(int i=0; i<thCNT; i++){
        mTH[i] = std::async(f, i+5);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<thCNT; i++){
        mTH[i].get();
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

code like above
xcode show an error like this, I dont know how to solve it.

I copy the code from an instruction, I hope to know if there is anything different between C++20  and C++11, since the instruction is made by C++11.

Comment: Is this the full error? There's usually more info about the possibilities and why they failed. In addition, there should be a warning about passing a non-int to %d.

Comment: The function `f` doesn't return int as the future expects.

Comment: `mTH[thCNT];` is not valid C++ unless you make `thCNT`  `const` or `constexpr`.

Answer (score 0):

273K is right.
I should return int when use future like below:

```
int f(int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("Thread[%d]: %d\n",std::this_thread::get_id(), i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```